# How to print blinking text that blinks between two different text while blinking python

Tags: python

I have to print statements and I would like the print statements to blink between both statements. I am trying to figure out how to print hello world and for it to blink to How are you?

I am using imageDraw to draw an output for the text and termcolor library is not working with python 3.8. Please let me know if there is another way to do this.

> print("Hello World")

> print("How are you?")

Answer (score 0):

There is a native way to do this without any libraries by using [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#:%7E:text=EL-,Erase%20in%20Line,-Erases%20part%20of).

You can also use carriage returns in combination to 'replace' the text printed.

```py
import sys
from time import sleep

print('Hello World', end='\r')
sleep(1)

for _ in range(5):  # Change to control no. of 'blinks'
    print('How are you?', end='\r')
    sleep(1)  # To create the blinking effect
    sys.stdout.write('\033[2K\r')  # Clears the entire line and carriage returns
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: It does not clear the entire line when it blinks on the output terminal

Comment: turns out that it doesn't work right on IDLE on windows, but works when running it via terminal (linux)